# How do I segue to different detail view controllers?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

In a split view controller app,how can I segue to different detail view controllers upon selecting a table row in the master view controller?

Just to be clear, I need the detail view controller to be replaced when I select a row in the master view controller.  How do I wire up the view controllers?  From the split view controller?  or from the detail view navigation controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in the master table view's delegate. Depending on the value of the `indexPath` parameter, call `[detailViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]` with the segue identifier of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

In your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

If you need to perform different segues based on the selected row, do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *segueIdentifier = nil;

    switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            segueIdentifier = @"YourSegueIdentifier";
            break;
        case 1:
            segueIdentifier = @"ADifferentSegueIdentifier";
            break;
        .
        .
        .
    }

    if (segueIdentifier != nil) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get detail navigation controller
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

// Push the detail view controller
[detailNavigationController pushViewController:anyDetailViewController animated:NO];

// You also might need to set the splitview controller's delegate to this view controller
splitViewController.delegate = anyDetailViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController =[[[self splitViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];                
  [detailNavigationController pushViewController:"your_view_controller" animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your segue, set your style to "Push", and your destination to "Detail". Current will push the destination view controller onto your Master view, whereas Detail will push it into the "Detail" view. It's that simple. Then wire it up the same way you wire everything else up.

**But be careful**, if you don't implement a way for it to wait for a previous segue, you can get an "Unbalanced calls" error if a new Controller is pushed onto the detail view before it's done dismissing/pushing another one. Double tapping a cell in a table will do it.